Issues receiving raw frames with RFM69HCW on ESP32 using esp-idf
I am programming an ESP32 using the esp-idf framework to receive data from an RFM69HCW radio frequency module. The problem is that I cannot receive raw frames, despite having configured pin G02 as specified in the module's datasheet.
I am using this library: esp-idf-rf69
Here is the module's datasheet: RFM69HCW Datasheet
So far, I have managed to get the two radio frequency modules to communicate with each other, but I am unable to receive raw data from other devices, such as my garage remote control.
Has anyone faced a similar issue or have any suggestions on how to resolve this? I would appreciate any help or advice on what I might be doing wrong or what settings I should check.
I have tried configuring it in continuous mode and receiving data through pin G02 of the RFM69HCW, but it still doesn't pick up any transmissions.

Your garage remote isn't a LoRa transceiver... You won't be able to receive non-LoRa packets.

But the rfm69hw it isnt a lora module, it should be able to comunicate with garage remote by OOK (also known as ASK)

So... what is the lora tag for then?

It was an error
